# How to calculate a row-major index when each matrix cell is itself a matrix?

Tags: algorithm, rust

This is an implementation I've made of the game of life in rust, pretty basic, and I wanted to shoot my sot at trying to make a gui app, so after a bit of scramblying I came across minifb(not relevant, but context, as this buffer then goes to update_with_buffer() method).
To make a long story short, I am looking up my grid matrix, then, according to some scale, filling up "squares" of pixels in the buffer's 1d array, then printing to the screen according to it. This is the code (a reduced version not to bore you with extra functions):

```rust
for y in 0..rows {
    for x in 0..cols {
        let color = if grid[y][x] == 1 { 0xFFFFFF } else { 0x000000 };
        for py in 0..vert_scale {
            for px in 0..horiz_scale {
                let pixel_id = x * rows as usize * vert_scale * horiz_scale
                    + y * vert_scale * horiz_scale
                    + px * vert_scale
                    + py;
                buffer[pixel_id] = color;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My real problem is in the let pixel_id line, as I think my algorithmic aproach doesn't work, I can provide more code if this doesn't sufice, such as the grid and buffer generator and everything.

This buffer should be a 1d array which could be inputed to the update_with_buffer and correspond to what I can see in the grid matrix in the cmd.

I've tried a lot of definitions of pixel_id, and although I don't care if it emerges rotated(if I where confusing rows and colums or this buffer was printed from the top left, bottom left), this implementation is the only one I've had that actually makes squares instead of a blinking window or lines.

- The only one that's brought up squares thus far: `let pixel_id = y * cols as usize * horiz_scale + x * vert_scale * rows + px * py;`
- Afore mentioned blinking window attemp(although this is the on I'm most recently secure about): `let pixel_id = x * rows as usize * vert_scale * horiz_scale + y * vert_scale * horiz_scale + px * vert_scale+ py;`
- One of the afore mentioned lines attemp?(there where a lot of these): `let pixel_idx = ((y * vert_scale + py) * (cols as usize * horiz_scale)+ x * horiz_scale+ px) as usize;`

Either way, thank you for the attention thus far and I hope to be corrected, this is a pretty embarazing confusing mess that I just can't manage to get out of my head neither complete correctly.

Comment: Arrgh are you sure it's correct though, after some more thought I think it should be `(y * vert_scale + py) * cols * horiz_scale + x * horiz_scale + px` instead. i.e. I forgot to scale the `x` and `y` properly.

Comment: @cafce25 I think I found both the culprit to my problems and the solution to my question, first of, I'd like to formaly apraise you, as your solution seems to work as intended in the end after some tooling around, if you may post it as an anwser, I'll be glad to mark it as the solution. Secondly, my problem: It basically boiled down to , in the method update_with_buffer(), while passing the dimensions of the array, passing on the number of rows and cols, without multiplying for scale, leading to all sort of weird bugs; it was completely on my part, although I also had the algo part wrong so :D

Comment: Well couldn't have helped you with that as you didn't make your example [completely reproducible](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let me walk through my lines of thought when coming up with the formula:

- First we have to differentiate are the pixels stored in column-major or row-major order. And seeing as [`minifb`s source code sets the stride to `width`](https://docs.rs/minifb/latest/src/minifb/lib.rs.html#349) I was fairly confident it's row-major
- Then for a row-major format each row is going to be placed in one contiguous block in the array. To index into that slice all we have to do is to get the pixel column we're in. Since each `grid` cell should be `horiz_scale` pixels wide that index is `x * horiz_scale` for the offset of the cell we're in plus `px` for the pixel of the cell so `x * horiz_scale + px`.
- Next we have to get the row we're in, analogous to the considerations about the column we get `y * vert_scale + py` then with that knowledge it's easy to calculate the offset for the row it's simply `number of rows before * total canvas width` or in terms of your code `(y * vert_scale + py) * (cols * horiz_scale)`
- And finally we just have to add the offset into the row to the offset of the row giving us a final `let pixel_id = (y * vert_scale + py) * cols * horiz_scale + x * horiz_scale + px`

Putting it all together this is some code that draws `grid` with 'pixels' of `horiz_scale * vert_scale` each onto the canvas that's `WIDTH * HEIGHT` big using [`minifb`](https://docs.rs/minifb/latest/minifb/).

```rust
use minifb::{Window, WindowOptions};

const HEIGHT: usize = 600;
const WIDTH: usize = 300;
fn main() {
    let options = WindowOptions::default();
    let mut window = Window::new("main", WIDTH, HEIGHT, options).unwrap();
    let mut buf = [0; HEIGHT * WIDTH];
    let horiz_scale = 10;
    let vert_scale = 10;
    let rows = HEIGHT / vert_scale;
    let cols = WIDTH / horiz_scale;

    let mut grid = vec![vec![false; cols]; rows];

    loop {
        // let start = std::time::Instant::now();
        // update grid
        for y in 0..rows {
            for x in 0..cols {
                for py in 0..vert_scale {
                    for px in 0..horiz_scale {
                        let color = if grid[y][x] { 0xFFFFFF } else { 0x000000 };
                        let pixel_id = (y * vert_scale + py) * WIDTH + x * horiz_scale + px;
                        buf[pixel_id] = color;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        window.update_with_buffer(&buf, WIDTH, HEIGHT).unwrap();
        // std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(16).saturating_sub(start.elapsed()));
    }
}
```